# Rounding function to nearest 1/4

Tags: c#, asp.net, rounding

We only want to auto round the user entered values to the nearest .25 hour interval. So the user can enter 1.55 and it would round to 1.50 when saving to the database. If the user enters 1.90 to would save 2.00 to the database.

Comment: 1.55 -> 1.50 is not a "round up", but rather "down" or "to nearest". There are multiple rounding schemes (like odd-even for taxes etc), so make sure to be clear about that when finishing the code.

Comment: Also be careful to always perform the rounding in the same place. I.e., if you put it in your SQL, always do it in your SQL. And if you put it in your C# code (which is where I'd try to put it), then always do it there. Different implementations will behave differently for the edge cases, and it's bound to cause problems later down the line, like, the screen will show one number but the printed report shows another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0.25` is 1/4, so you can get it easily by

```
double rounded = round(4.0 * hoursEntered) / 4.0
```

`round` does not exist. You must use appropriate rounding function and options. For aspx.cs (C# codebehind) see `System.Math.Round`.

Also, to link it to the textbox on the webpage, you will need some rule/validator or textchange handler or anywhere around the typical text parsing. You may also try doing it in JavaScript client side, the *4/4 trick stays the same, just `round` function will have different name.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [`MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
double d = 1.55 * 4;
double i = Math.Round(d, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
Console.WriteLine(i / 4);
```

Output will be

```
1.5
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/z9dJVI)</kbd>.

As an explanation, multiplying 4 and then rounding gives you exactly 4 times with your decimal part like `.00`, `.25`, `.50`, `.75`.

Than dividing this double to `4`, gives you exactly nearest `.25` hour interval.

Here a full codes of examples;

```
double[] array = new[] { 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.25, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.55, 1.6, 1.7, 1.75, 1.8, 1.9 };
foreach (double item in array)
{
    double d = item * 4;
    double i = Math.Round(d, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    Console.WriteLine(i / 4);
}
```

Output will be;

```
1.0 gives you 1.0
1.1 gives you 1.0
1.2 gives you 1.25
1.25 gives you 1.25
1.3 gives you 1.25
1.4 gives you 1.5
1.5 gives you 1.5
1.55 gives you 1.5
1.6 gives you 1.5
1.7 gives you 1.75
1.75 gives you 1.75
1.8 gives you 1.75
1.9 gives you 2.0
```

Here a <kbd>[`full demonstration`](http://ideone.com/wQXRF1)</kbd>.

Comment: Nice and clean solution

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should do it:

```
double value = 1.55;    
double roundedValue = Math.Round(value/.25)*.25;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ToInt32()` conversion function as follows:

```
double x = input_value;
x = x * 4;
int y = Toint32(x);
x = ((double) y) / 4;
```

I think that would work. I see that there are other more elegant solutions, though.

Answer (score -2):

The Math.Round method is called several times. Because the .NET Framework differentiates between a decimal type and a double type, the best overloads are automatically chosen. You can call Math.Round with one to three arguments.
Read [this article](http://www.dotnetperls.com/math-round)

Comment: "called several times"..? what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry its just a mistake .Try to read the article http://www.dotnetperls.com/math-round